# Postgres server not starting up

Tags: database, postgresql, restart

I made a hard restart of my machine. After that, I am unable to start my server.

I killed the process listed in `postmaster.pid` and also removed the file. Now if I start the server using

```
pg_ctl start
```

it shows

> Fatal : The database system is starting up

for very long time, which does not normally happen.

Can someone please help me in finding the root cause of it?

Answer (score 0):

Open your postgresql.conf and turn off the "hot_standby" option, and then restart the service with **service postgresql restart**.

Comment: actually, after one and a half half hour it got started. By the way, i tried your way as well.